# Theme Not Applying to Dock

Tags: unity, icons, themes

So I am very new to Ubuntu and I am just beginning to learn the ins and outs of the OS. I am trying to apply a theme to the desktop. I have installed unity tweak tool and I know how to apply themes through it. My problem is that when I apply the theme through the tweak tool, it is applied everywhere except the dock. The icons change everywhere but the dock. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What dock? Cairo ? Docky?

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong word. It is the windows-type thing that sits on the left side of the screen. I have not installed anything else.

Comment: The unity launcher ? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's it! I'm a noob sry.

Comment: Have you tried reset unity launcher ?